# Utilização do ponto de interrogação REST

Tags: rest

Tenho uma lista de valores em tela que conforme o usuário for digitando será filtrada as opções. Caso o usuário deseje visualizar todos os registros ele digitará: ?;

Então a minha chamada do rest ficará: meuservidor/buscar/?

Pelo que entendi, esse "?" é interpretado como o início da declaração das variáveis, porém eu queria capturar o "?" para saber se devo retornar todos os registros.

Minha dúvida é se tem como eu mandar apenas o ponto de interrogação de alguma forma ou teria que dar um replace e enviar um "*" talvez..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você realmente quiser seguir a especificação `REST`, uma requisição `GET` sem parâmetros para o *endpoint* deverá resultar no retorno de todos os registros.

```
meuservidor/buscar
```

Resultará na lista completa.

Vamos dizer que um elemento de sua busca seja a coleção **Animal**. Você pode entar retornar o elemento como parte do path:

```
meuservidor/buscar/animal
```

Porém se você quiser passar parâmetros de pesquisa (não uma especificação de elemento), utilize a querystring (literamente *string de pergunta*):

```
meuservidor/buscar?nome=gato
```

Para retornar todos os registros cuja propriedade `nome` seja igual a `gato`, ou

```
meuservidor/buscar/animal?nome=gato
```

Para retornar todos os registros da coleção `animal` cuja propriedade `nome` seja igual a `gato`.

Comment: Legal..de fato é melhor assim, eu que havia complicado e não pensei pelo simples.

Answer (score 1):

É possível utilizar a "?" na URL, mas você teria que substituí-la pela sua codificação: **%3F**. Nesse caso, tua URL seria:

```
meuservidor/buscar/%3F
```

Comportamento semelhante é adotado quando a URL possui espaços em branco.